# Android Navigation Component: Restoring Navigation when jumping to a destination

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

We have a requirement where a user may do:

`EntryPoint` -> `A` -> `B` -> `C` -> `D` -> `...`

but the with the flow (for example user is in `C`), the user may choose to close the application.

But when the user goes back to the application and try again, the user must be restored back to `C` but also be able to generate the whole backstack of destinations before it. So in this case, the backstack must be:

`EntryPoint` -> `A` -> `B` -> `C`

so that when user press back, the user goes back to `B`.

I've tried jumping to `C` from `EntryPoint` with:

`NavController.navigate(destinationId)`

but this only jump to the destination without the backstack.

`EntryPoint` -> `C`

How should I restore the whole backstack?

Comment: Did you solve issue?